# Retrieve nested information from a .JSP File/Form in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

I'm studying Spring MVC and I can't figure out how to retrieve nested information from a form in a .jsp file to my controller.

Let's say I have a form page where the user put information about a `Goal` and multiple `Exercise`, each one represents one Object, so the POJO of `Goal` would be something like that:

```
public class Goal{
    private List<Exercise> exercises = new ArrayList<Exercise>();
    ...
}
```

And my controller, something like that:

```
@Controller
public class GoalController {
    
    @Autowired
    private GoalService goalService;
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "addGoal", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateGoal(@ModelAttribute("goal") Goal goal)   {

        goalService.save(goal); 
        return "redirect:index.jsp";
    }
}
```

The problem in this case is, I know how to get the `Goal` prior information, but I don't know how to get the `Exercise` information that is nested.

I've looked for some information about it, but just found articles talking about how to *show* nested information on the page, not *retrieve* it.

How should my .jsp page be structured to allow this?

Comment: Try this. Use a **getter** method to get the list of exercises from your `goal` object. `List<Exercises> e = goal.getExercises()`. Next iterate over this list like `for(Exercise ex : e) { ex.getParameter() ... }`. Tell me if this works.

Comment: Thanks @SajibAcharya but one more thing, how my .jsp file should be structured to make it possible?

Comment: Though this is out of your current question context, but I thought you already knew how to do that since you mentioned you went through some tutorials. Anyway, look into [this](http://bitbybitblog.com/forms-and-data-models-in-spring-mvc/) tutorial, this'll give you a pretty good idea of what to do. We need to use wrapper classes and use spring forms since spring forms can handle only one object at a time. Or else if you are stuck, you should really ask a new question on that, as it literally forms a new question far apart from the current context.

Comment: That's the point, the form, with one object I can handle, the problem is when dealing with two objects, especially when one is nested inside the other like in the example I've described above.

Comment: You cannot create a form with two objects. Since you can send only one object from within the Model. Use wrapper classes to literally wrap multiple classes as one.

Comment: ah! Okay I got it, thanks very much!